# Display Bing Map on Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, crm, bing-maps

I've been trying to cutomize the display of Address Bing Map Location in CRM form. Instead of displaying it by default, I want it to display on modal popup. So once the user clicked on the address, the modal popup should display with the Map on it. What do you guys think is the better approach should I used? Should I just enable the Showing of Bing Maps through system configuration then hide it by default once the page is loaded, then append it to the modal once the address is clicked or just make a function that will create a bing Map? Actually I'm working on the second choice but didn't able to make it right. Here's the code I have so far, been using this through console, yes it display the Map but really dont have an Idea what credentials should I put.

```
`$("#address1_composite").click(function(){
      alert();
      var map = null;  
      map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('SDKmap'), null)
 })
```

Hope that my explanation is clear enough to understand the requirement.

`

Comment: Research the expected amount of use of the map. If widely used: create at once. Look at this [code](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/bing/Bing-Maps-for-JavaScript-84f1effc/sourcecode?fileId=53417&pathId=1713588077) for more inspiration

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend that you load the map ahead of time, or delay until it is first needed, but then only hide/show it using your click events. Otherwise a user code end up loading the map multiple times in a single page view which would generate lot of transactions and make it very costly very fast.